# Limits Rational Fn missing p and q

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, roots, rational-functions

$f(x)=\frac{4z^3x^2-3x-7z}{3x^2+2x-1}$

Find all values of $z$ for which the limit of $x$ as $x$ goes to $-1$ of $f(x)$ exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Since the denominator tends to zero, for the existence of the limit we need that

$$4z^3x^2-3x-7z \to 0 \iff 4z^3-7z+3=0$$

Comment: Why is second equation implied?  Why remove x?

Comment: @JDragon314159 As $x \to -1$ we have that $4z^3x^2-3x-7z \to 4z^3-7z+3$ and we need $4z^3-7z+3=0$, otherwise the limit can't exist.

Comment: Very Good!  Then, seems only one real number will work.  TYVM

Comment: @JDragon314159 Note that $z=1$ is a root but maybe it is not the only one. You can use long division of $4z^3-7z+3$ by $z-1$ to check that.

Comment: No remainder so it is a factor.  Thing there is a fractional root too but it is negative.

Comment: @JDragon314159 It seems we have three roots by [wolfy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4z%5E3-7z%2B3%3D0)

Comment: Very Good.  Thanks for the 3rd one.

Comment: @JDragon314159 You are welcome bye!